# Difficulty Grasping Controllers Using Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, controller

I'm trying to build an online showcase/store for my artwork and I'm having a little trouble starting. I've decided to use rails after some advice from friends.

My one question is regarding controllers. Do I need a controller for every page?

As of now, I plan to have a Home, Contact, Products, and About Us page in my HTML. Does this require me to have four different controllers?

Let me know if you have any input and thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, for this case you can have a `PagesController` with various actions - home, contact, about us.

As for products, this rather sounds like a separate controller with at least an index and show action.

For your *static* pages, you can make named routes for clean urls without the pages prefix, like this:

```
match 'about-us' => 'pages#about_us', :as => :about_us
```

Then you can use `about_us_path`and `about_us_url` in your views

Comment: This seems fair. However, what if on each of the static pages, I were to include a dynamic function such as a sidebar with featured products? How would the MVC come into play then?

Comment: Doesnt really change anything on the implementation. You would have the dynamic code in your models, feed your controller and display a partial.

Comment: @TopChef You would put that in your view via a partial, and then you need to put whatever variable you have into a controller. Depending on how you do it it can either be a products controller or an application controller. Have you checked out the rails tutorial by MH? Work through that a time or two and it will definitely get you to understand all this MVC stuff.

Comment: The controller would still ask the model (products) for objects and pass them to the view, where you would probably render a partial. This leads of course to a controller with multiple responsibilities. [Cells](http://cells.rubyforge.org/) can definitely clean this up, by providing a separate 'MVC'-Stack

Answer (score 5):

Your controllers need to be *topically* based, not *page* based. So as @topek mentioned, static pages can go into a pages controller. Pages dealing with management of a Product class can go into a Products controller.

Really, this is not a Rails question. This is an MVC question.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, a controller represents a resource in your web application(REST design). A product is definitely a controller on its own that has actions like new, edit and so on.

Now, you can go about creating a single controller that handles home, contact and about us, but i vote against it. I personally would definitely use different controllers for each.

I prefer to have everything as isolated as possible, just to have my code more open for extension and closed for changes(open/closed design principle).

Answer (score -1):

Learn about the role of controllers in RESTful Rails-style MVC. While REST is not applicable to everything, it will give you some idea of what (at least in Rails) a controller is expected to do.